# Text box not showing total

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In my program I want to add some values together with a running total, and then show that total in a text box. When I try to run it, though, it just shows zero.

Here's the code I'm using

```
        TotalPrice = TotalPrice + Price
    Next
    TxtLuggage.Text = TotalPrice
```

this chunk was a part of a For next loop.

How do I fix this.

Comment: more code around your loop. More info about textbox. WinForms/WebForms/WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Please do not take this as an offense, but I think you should read some book or at least a decent article on .NET debugging. This one looks like an easy to spot with just a bit of basic debugging.

See [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290042%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for example, and pay special attention on stepping through code, setting breakpoints and watches

What you should do:

- set a breakpoint in the code in the problematic code line
- when debugger breaks code execution there, see which object are you changing the property for. Does this property change the text box text value? Are you using a correct form instance?
- does the For..Next loop set it to zero on its final pass?